# Patron decorator private attributes set to 0.0

Tags: java, decorator, abstract

I'm trying to learn decorator pattern. Here's a really simple character design which should be able to equipt different objects. The problem comes when all the attributes of the character are set to 0.

```
public abstract class Character{
    private double damage;
    public Character();
    public void setDamage(damage){
         this.damage = damage;
    }
    public double getDamage(){return damage;}

}


public class Human extends Character{
    public Human(){
        damage = 10.00;
    }
}


public abstract class Object extends Character{
    public abstract String getDescription();
}


public class Sword extends Object{
    Character character;

    public Sword(Character character){
        this.character = character;
        updateDamage();
    }
    public String getDescription(){
          // Something
    }

    public void updateDamage(){
         character.setDamage(character.getDamage() + 2.00);
    }
}
```

Here's a simple output.

```
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args){
         Character test = new Human();
         System.out.printl(test.getDamage());
         test = new Sword(test);
         System.out.printl(test.getDamage());
 }

 // OUTPUT
 10.0
 0.0
```

Why is this happening? Is there a better implementation than the decorator patter for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following line :

```
new Sword(test);
```

will not set the damage of the sword object but the one from the test (human) decorated. The Sword constructor will call the updateDamage method that does not set the damage field.

To make this code working, you should change the updateDamage method from Sword :

```
public void updateDamage(){
     setDamage(character.getDamage() + 2.00);
}
```